# Should there be cold air returns in my bathrooms?

Tags: hvac

Should a heat vent be open when no return is present in a room. I have 2 bathrooms with showers that have heat vents but no returns. Pls let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Bathrooms never have returns. You wouldn't want humidity and odor distributed throughout your house. Bathrooms in modern homes may have exhaust vents that route through a heat exchanger. This still results in the air being vented to the exterior though.

Also, it used to be common for bedrooms to have heat supplies but no cold air returns. There may have been a central return in the hallway or other common area.

Comment: But if you simply pressurize the bathroom, the effect will be to push the stinky under the door, into the hall, and throughout the house. Exhaust fans only work when they're turned on, and they are not Code in the US if there's a window.

Comment: warm air and methane rises and cold air falls.  That is why the doors are cut off; to allow the air closest to the floor to escape into the hall and find its way to a return air opening.

Answer (score 0):

The exhaust fan acts as a “relief air” vent. Exhaust fans have a backdraft damper (flap) that allows air out, but not in.